# Bootstrap Carousel-controls not clickable and not working in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help please. I've tried switching from `bootstrap.min.js` to `bootstrap.js`; from `jquery.min.js` to `jquery.js`. The animation works perfectly but no control is clickable or working. Is it a problem with ASP.NET MVC5?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/font-awsome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/CADF6E67-D04A-8F45-8DD6-5103EA07CB3E/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/E3BC70AE3015-6DD8-54F8-A40D-76E6FDAC/abn/main.css"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    .min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        var WindowsSize=function(){
            var h=$(window).height(),
                w=$(window).width();
            $("#winSize").html("<p>Width: "+w+"<br>Height: "+h+"</p>");
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){WindowsSize();});
        $(window).resize(function(){WindowsSize();});
    </script>       
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50" style="border:0px solid black; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top opaque-navbar"  style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; display:inline-block; width:100%">
                <button id="menuBarButton" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" 
                        style="border:0;margin-top:0px;background-color:#ffffff; outline:none">
                    <span id="bar1" class="icon-bar" style="border:0; background-color:#17508d; height:3px; width:35px"></span>
                    <span id="bar2" class="icon-bar" style="border:0; background-color:#17508d; height:3px; width:35px"></span>
                    <span id="bar3" class="icon-bar" style="border:0; background-color:#17508d; height:3px; width:35px"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-top:0px; border:0; padding-top:6px; position:fixed">
                    <img style="height:56px; margin-left:3px; padding-top:0px; image-resolution:snap; image-rendering:optimizeQuality" 
                         src="/Content/Images/DcmpLogos/dcmpLogo12.png"/>
                </a>
                <div id="topest-menu-nav" style="float:right">
                    <div class="social-links-ontop" style="display:inline-block; background-color:#17508d;padding-left:12px;"><a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size:20px"></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-links-ontop" style="display:inline-block;background-color:#13cf33; padding-left:9px"><a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="font-size:20px"></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-links-ontop"style="display:inline-block; background-color:#2bccd7;padding-left:8px;"><a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:20px"></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-links-ontop" style="display:inline-block; background-color:#a91515;padding-left:7px;">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="fa fa-youtube-play" style="font-size:20px"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <div class="section-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin:0px;">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:larger"></i> HOME</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="10" data-close-others="false"
                               href="#">DEPARTMENTS & SERVICES</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top:3px; min-width:100%;border-radius:0px">
                                <li><a href="#">DIRECTION</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">SALES & PROCUREMENT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">QUALITY ASSURANCE</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PARTNERS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li style="padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px;">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="10" data-close-others="false"
                               href="#"><span class="fa fa-globe" style="font-size:20px; font-weight:normal"></span> Switch Language</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width:100%; margin-top:3px; border-radius:0px">
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="lang-sm" lang="en"></span> ENGLISH</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="lang-sm" lang="fr"></span> FRANCAIS</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--<section class="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Transparent Background Example</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>-->

    <div class="container-fluid" style="z-index:0;">



<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="item1 active"></li>
        <li class="item2" onclick="showitem2()"></li>
        <li class="item3" id="item3Id"></li>
        <li class="item4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/Content/Images/HomeCarousel/5821d1693.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>...</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/HomeCarousel/5821d1693.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>...</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/HomeCarousel/5821d1693.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Carousel 3</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/HomeCarousel/5821d1693.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>...</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            // Enable Carousel Animation
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 2000
            });
            // Enable Carousel Indicators
            $('.item1').click(function () {
                $('.carousel').carousel(0);
            });
            $('.item2').click(function () {
                $('carousel').carousel(1);
            });
            $('item').click(function () {
                $('carousel').carousel(2);
            });
            $('.item4').click(function () {
                $('.carousel').carousel(3);
            });

            // Enable Carousel Controls
            $('.left').click(function () {
                $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
            });
            $('.right').click(function () {
                $("#myCarousel").carousel("next");
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might find better response if you read - and implement - the guidance in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also please don't shout.

Comment: Do not shout!!! Please try to be polite.

Comment: Sorry for that! I didn't know was shouting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very sorry to bother you, since the problem was kindly crazy.
I finally got the problem. I had changed the property

> .navbar-collapse{ min-height :900px; color: transparent;}

**unknowingly on my drafts in a .css file**, yet its z-index is higher than the carousel's by default. So there's no way the carousel would be clickable, since it was covered...
Thank you indeed for you interest though!